# Unsure of where to place def() and return functions to split code and get second choice to run

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run a quick game where the user first inputs an integer from 2-10 then inputs an integer of 1 or 2. The first choice allows for calculations to be performed on it by the second input. The second input has two games, countdown and factorial. I have the first choice running, and the code for the second choice mainly down, but I'm trying to figure out to have them run as functions where after you run either choice and completes, it prompts you to choose again.

I've tried searching the forums and looking up videos on functions but keep running into errors. Tried placing the def main(): and return in different sections of code and getting errors.

```
# user instructions for section 1
def opening ():
    print('Please enter a number from 2 to 10 in the first prompt.')
    print('In the second prompt, please choose 1 or 2 to play a number game')

opening ()


num_choice = int(input('Enter a number from 2 to 10 to begin: '))
num_choice2 = int(input('Now pick 1 for countdown or 2 for factorial: '))


if num_choice <= 1 : # error message because user can't follow directions
    print('please choose from the number range provided')

# user choice branches
if num_choice2 == 1 :
print('Countdown from %d\n:' % num_choice)
elif num_choice2 == 2:
    print('factorial for %d\n:' % num_choice)

# countdown loop function
while num_choice >= 2 :
    print(num_choice)
    num_choice -= 1

#factorial game instructions
if num_choice == 0:
    print("\n The factorial of 0 is 1");
elif num_choice < 0:
    print("\n Negative numbers get this done..!!");
else:
    factor = 1;
    for i in range(1, num_choice+1):
        factor = factor*i;
    print("\nFactorial of", num_choice, "is", factor);
```

So far, the first function, and countdown game are working as intended, the rest is as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my understanding of your question, i have restructured your code for better readability and provided with the solution you wanted. Hope this helps

```
def opening ():
    print('Please enter a number from 2 to 10 in the first prompt.')
    print('In the second prompt, please choose 1 or 2 to play a number game')

def countdown(num_choice):
     while num_choice >= 2 :
        print(num_choice)
        num_choice -= 1

def factorial(num_choice):
    if num_choice == 0:
        print("\n The factorial of 0 is 1");
    elif num_choice < 0:
        print("\n Negative numbers get this done..!!");
    else:
        factor = 1;
        for i in range(1, num_choice+1):
            factor = factor*i;
        print("\nFactorial of", num_choice, "is", factor);

while(True):
    opening ()
    num_choice = int(input('Enter a number from 2 to 10 to begin: '))
    num_choice2 = int(input('Now pick 1 for countdown or 2 for factorial: '))

    if num_choice <= 1 : # error message because user can't follow directions
        print('please choose from the number range provided')
        continue

    # user choice branches
    if num_choice2 == 1 :
        print('Countdown from %d:\n' % num_choice)
        countdown(num_choice)
    elif num_choice2 == 2:
        print('factorial for %d:\n' % num_choice)
        factorial(num_choice)

    if(input("do you want to replay?(y/n): ")=='y'):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I appreciate the help on this. I'm still new to programming and while I understand the basic functions and expressions workings, placement is where I get caught up at. I'm sure with time, I'll get better, but for now, its a challenge.

Comment: I noticed that for some reason this section of code is not running. I tried some changes and am still getting nothing for output on incorrect choices of negative integers, 0, and 1.

Comment: Here's the current version of the code section I'm talking about:

def factorial(num_choice): # factorial game instructions
    if num_choice == 0:
        print("\n The factorial of 0 is 1");
    elif num_choice < 0:
        print("\n Negative numbers ain't it chief..!!");
    else:
        factor = 1;
        for i in range(1, num_choice+1):
            factor = factor*i;
        print("\nFactorial of", num_choice, "is", factor);
        factorial(num_choice)

Comment: Hi, i have tested your code and it seems to work fine with all scenarios. If you could tell me the exact problem or error you faced it would be helpful. I still did some minor changes to you code for better formatting of output.

def factorial(num_choice): # factorial game instructions
 factor=1
 if num_choice == 0: 
  print("\n The factorial of 0 is 1")
 elif num_choice < 0: 
  print("\n Negative numbers ain't it chief..!!")
 else:
  for i in range(1, num_choice+1): 
   factor = factor*i
  print("\nFactorial of", num_choice, "is", factor)

factorial(num_choice)